# What is the `<<-EOSQL` code block in Bash when running SQL?

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, environment-variables

I need to execute a bash script containing SQL, so I am using a script to add custom configurations to a Postgres Docker container, according to the docs here:

https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#how-to-extend-this-image

But I don't know what `EOSQL` means. Here is an example of my script taken from the docs above:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE docker;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;
    CREATE EXTENSION $MY_EXTENSION;
EOSQL
```

So, what is EOSQL? I cannot seem to find much information about this command or keyword.

Comment: The code is fine; are you sure `MY_EXTENSION` was exported before running this script?

Comment: `EOSQL` isn't a keyword; it's just an arbitrary string (End Of SQL) used to mark the boundaries of the here document.

Comment: Ah yes, the environment variables are working just fine. I was having another error, which I thought was caused by the environment variables failing to load. I updated my question to be about the EOSQL block and the Bash Here Document, which was the cause of my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`EOSQL` is a limit string for a [Here Document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) block. The limit string signifies the start and end of a text block to the bash interpreter (or any POSIXy shell). The limit string can be any text that doesn't appear in your block, `EOF` is common in examples.

The content of the heredoc is directed to standard input of the process preceding it.

Variable substitution will work as normal in the here document (as long as the limit string is not quoted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat <<-EOF
    a
    $MY_EXTENSION
    b
EOF
echo "script continues" > /dev/null
```

Then running the scripts the `MY_EXTENSION` variable set will expand the variables and `cat` the content of the heredoc:

```
$ MY_EXTENSION=something ./test.sh
a
something
b
```

In Docker you will need `ENV MY_EXTENSION=something` in your `Dockerfile` or `docker run -e MY_EXTENSION=something <image>` on the command line for the environment to be setup.

#### Leading tabs

Both `<<EOSQL` and `<<-EOSQL` are valid ways to start a heredoc.

The `<<-EOSQL` includes a `-` to ignore the leading tab characters on any lines of the heredoc.

Using `<<EOSQL` would leave any leading tabs in the heredoc output.